# Listen for dispatchKeyEvent whilst app is in the background

Tags: android

The application I'm writing must listen for a physical hardware button click event from outside of my app. My device has a **dedicated SOS button** that I'm trying to use.

Up to now I can use the **dispatchKeyEvent** from within my app but this is no good, I need to find a way of listening for this key event when my app is in the **background**.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    // sos button code = 80;
    if(event.getKeyCode() == 80){
        // SOS button clicked
        // run function here.
        Toast.makeText(this, "SoS button clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: "The application I'm writing must listen for a physical hardware button click event from outside of my app" -- that is not possible, except on rooted devices, custom ROMs, or manufacturer support (e.g., system broadcast when the button is clicked). "My device has a dedicated SOS button that I'm trying to use" -- ask the device manufacturer how to respond to that button click from the background.

Comment: You might also put the device at its home screen (or the equivalent, something that should not have your `dispatchKeyEvent()` code), press the SOS button, and examine LogCat to see what messages are logged. They might hint at a system broadcast or something that the manufacturer added, triggered by that button.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'll give that a go now thanks! Also I have the ability to create a custom ROM and flash it onto the device, Any ideas on where to go from there, would installing the app as a system app help at all?

Comment: Well, once you get into custom ROMs, you can do all sorts of things. I would look into seeing in the AOSP code how the CAMERA button is handled. That is a physical button on some devices, that if the foreground activity does not consume the key event, triggers a system broadcast. In your case, you might do something more specific than a broadcast, but leveraging the CAMERA button approach should get you most of the way there. There may be approaches for system apps to be able to peek into the input queue, consume this particular event, and pass the rest along, but I don't know the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't comment yet as I do not have 50 reputations, so apologies for the added string here.  So I am also working on this and I can share what I have done.

Firstly we looked at the Generic.kl and other keylayout files that are found in the /system/usr/keylayout folders.  We can easily change the behaviour of any button in here but of course you are restricted to only the main system commands like CAMERA, VOLUME_UP, SEARCH etc.

So you can't run an app directly from here.

So we turned to the init.rc file you can find by cracking open the boot.img on the main ROM.  There's a great thread here about this:

[Running app from button press](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=695936)

So we added a script in the /system/bin folder.  I checked the script runs by running it manually in the shell.  I also tested with a basic echo script.

We then added the service in the init.rc file but it did not work.  In fact we tried to change the button listened for and nothing worked.  Very frustrating as there are services written in here by Android exactly the same.  We made sure that we removed all references to the buttons in the .kl files too, just in case they overrode the init.rc service.

So the service in the init.rc file must be the culprit, but not sure why yet.  So still stuck, very close, but so far away!!