# Listening to key press events blocks the keys from working

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android and I'm making an app that will listen for a consecutive volume up and volume down keypress and vibrate a pattern.

I've tried using dispatchKeyEvent() and it detects volume up and down fine but it blocks the user from changing the volume.

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                System.out.println("UP"); // I know i can use Log but this is quicker to type
            }
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                System.out.println("DOWN");
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Additionally I'd like to be able to do this when the screen is off (and app in background) but aparently services can't interact with key events.

I've found very conflicting answers all over the place; an app I used before played a sound when it was in the background, screen turned off and the power button was pressed 3 times in short succession, however many questions here have answers akin to "not possible".

I wouldn't mind using power button instead of volume keys (infact both would be nice) but that seems harder to implement.

> TLDR:
>
> 1. How to stop listeners blocking the keys they're listening.
>
>    <s>2. How to run this in the background.</s>

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: regarding no2 I found a way to do this with power button by registering a broadcast receiver in a service and listening to screen off and screen on intents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

overriding the `onKeyDown()` of `Activity` is easier; because it's always `KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN`:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP: {
            System.out.println("UP");
        }
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN: {
            System.out.println("DOWN");
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: @DavidPH here it is also explained: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846050/difference-between-onkey-onkeydown-and-dispatchkeyevent-methods-provided ...you were not listening to "key-press events" (as the title claims), but to key-dispatch events. overriding the framework's classes and calling/returning the over-riden method of the `super()` class might have the least side-effects. returning `true` for events means, that they have been consumed - and they won't bubble any further (which can be desired or undesired).

Answer (score 0):

> How to stop listeners blocking the keys they're listening.

As you could see from [android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchKeyEvent(android.view.KeyEvent)), if you don't need to block your keys, just call `super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);` otherwise if you `return true;` it means that you consumed event, nobody will know about event.

> How to run this in the background.

I think, there is impossible. Android has service, which could do background job, but this not way to handle system button clicks. [Maybe this topic will help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757616/listen-for-dispatchkeyevent-whilst-app-is-in-the-background)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer that stopped it from blocking the keys. 

As for the running in the background, I've seen apps that do this before but "impossible" seems to be the most common answer to this question everywhere. Absolutely baffling.

Comment: @DavidPH Tell purpose of this. Maybe change the way.

Comment: @Dimitro Ivanov I have a pattern I want to vibrate when the screen is off (app can be in the background while screen is off) and the user triggers it, that being by a combination of volume keys or by pressing the power key.

Comment: @DavidPH As you know, a volume keys and the power key already handled by the Android OS. This no common question, but keep going. Happy coding!